# ANT copy task: Filesystem diff to recognize file deletions

Tags: ant, directory, copy, filesystems, diff

In my project setting I have for example the following file system setting:

**Directory A**
file1

**Directory B**
file1
file2

I have a copy task in my ant script which copies the whole content of **Dir A** into **Dir B** with `overwrite=true`. But I want a task which recognizes that `file2` has been deleted in **Dir A** and therefore also deletes it in **Dir B**. This must be recognized for recursive directory hierarchies inside these two folders A and B. It is enough if it works only one way (A->B).

Is there anything available which does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to delete the content of `Directory B` before copying.